# How set logback as main logger in spring boot with spring data elasticsearch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, logback, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have spring boot v 2.0.0.M3 with default logger logback. When i add spring data elasticsearch v 3.0.0RC2 spring boot change main logger from logback to log4j
How I can set logback as main logger?

Comment: `I add` is that via `maven`? If so you can do `exclusions` on that spring-data-elasticsearch if it uses log4j

Comment: @Eugene Via gradle

Comment: this? https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependency/2119

Comment: What you have described shouldn't happen. Spring Boot will use Logback in preference to Log4j2 when both are on the classpath. Log4j is no longer supported as its EOL.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have both dependencies logback-classic-1.2.3 and log4j-api-2.8.2. But when I start app it use log4j default configs org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig

Comment: Aah, this is due to Spring Framework 5's new spring-jcl module that will use Log4j2 if available and SLF4J if it's not. You should exclude Log4j2 from your classpath as recommended by Eugene.